# change JsonRequest python in odoo

Tags: python, json, odoo

on success send data json to odoo in format like this

```
{
    "params":{
        "name":"admin",
        "age":"18"
        }
}
```

but I need to get data like this

```
{
        "name":"admin",
        "age":"18"
}
```

How can I do that?
I already find the code to change that, but I don't know how to change it

class JsonRequest(WebRequest):
""" Request handler for `JSON-RPC 2 <http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification>`_ over HTTP

```
* ``method`` is ignored
* ``params`` must be a JSON object (not an array) and is passed as keyword
  arguments to the handler method
* the handler method's result is returned as JSON-RPC ``result`` and
  wrapped in the `JSON-RPC Response
  <http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification#response_object>`_

Sucessful request::

  --> {"jsonrpc": "2.0",
       "method": "call",
       "params": {"context": {},
                  "arg1": "val1" },
       "id": null}

  <-- {"jsonrpc": "2.0",
       "result": { "res1": "val1" },
       "id": null}

Request producing a error::

  --> {"jsonrpc": "2.0",
       "method": "call",
       "params": {"context": {},
                  "arg1": "val1" },
       "id": null}

  <-- {"jsonrpc": "2.0",
       "error": {"code": 1,
                 "message": "End user error message.",
                 "data": {"code": "codestring",
                          "debug": "traceback" } },
       "id": null}

"""
_request_type = "json"

def __init__(self, *args):
    super(JsonRequest, self).__init__(*args)

    self.jsonp_handler = None

    args = self.httprequest.args
    jsonp = args.get('jsonp')
    self.jsonp = jsonp
    request = None
    request_id = args.get('id')
    
    if jsonp and self.httprequest.method == 'POST':
        # jsonp 2 steps step1 POST: save call
        def handler():
            self.session['jsonp_request_%s' % (request_id,)] = self.httprequest.form['r']
            self.session.modified = True
            headers=[('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=utf-8')]
            r = werkzeug.wrappers.Response(request_id, headers=headers)
            return r
        self.jsonp_handler = handler
        return
    elif jsonp and args.get('r'):
        # jsonp method GET
        request = args.get('r')
    elif jsonp and request_id:
        # jsonp 2 steps step2 GET: run and return result
        request = self.session.pop('jsonp_request_%s' % (request_id,), '{}')
    else:
        # regular jsonrpc2
        request = self.httprequest.stream.read()

    # Read POST content or POST Form Data named "request"
    try:
        self.jsonrequest = json.loads(request)
    except ValueError:
        msg = 'Invalid JSON data: %r' % (request,)
        _logger.info('%s: %s', self.httprequest.path, msg)
        raise werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequest(msg)

    self.params = dict(self.jsonrequest.get("params", {}))
    self.context = self.params.pop('context', dict(self.session.context))
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the following code in any of your controller before you initialize the controller class

```
from odoo import http
from odoo.http import request, Response, JsonRequest
from odoo.tools import date_utils

class JsonRequestNew(JsonRequest):

    def _json_response(self, result=None, error=None):

        # response = {
        #    'jsonrpc': '2.0',
        #    'id': self.jsonrequest.get('id')
        #    }
        # if error is not None:
        #    response['error'] = error
        # if result is not None:
        #    response['result'] = result

        responseData = super(JsonRequestNew, self)._json_response(result=result,error=error)

        response = {}
        if error is not None:
            response = error
        if result is not None:
            response = result

        mime = 'application/json'
        body = json.dumps(response, default=date_utils.json_default)

        return Response(
            body, status=error and error.pop('http_status', 200) or 200,
            headers=[('Content-Type', mime), ('Content-Length', len(body))]
        )

class RootNew(http.Root):

    def get_request(self, httprequest):
        
        # deduce type of request

        jsonResponse = super(RootNew, self).get_request(httprequest=httprequest)

        if httprequest.mimetype in ("application/json", "application/json-rpc"):
            return JsonRequestNew(httprequest)
        else:
            return jsonResponse

http.root = RootNew()

class MyController(http.Controller):
```